# iOS segue.destinationViewController doesn't send information

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm working on a **storyboard app** with the Spotify API. I used this (https://github.com/avazquezpr/SpotifyDemo) Github project as 'base'. But the thing is; this isn't a **storyboard app**. After you connect with Spotify, you will directly go to the Spotify player.

I prefer:

> connect spotify (ViewController) --> choose a playlist
>   (PlaylistController) --> go to player (PlayController)

The app is getting the login information at the `ViewController` and send them to the player. But in my case, the information must be sent through the `playlistMenuController`. But I think, there's something wrong with the `segue.destinationviewcontroller`.

`ViewController`:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToPlaylistMenu" {

            let destinationViewController: PlaylistController = segue.destinationViewController as! PlaylistController

            // Send current Spotify Session
            destinationViewController.currentSession = loginSession
        }
    }
```

`PlaylistController`:

```
lazy var currentSession = SPTSession()
var loginSession = SPTSession()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


// NAVIGATION
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToPlayer" {

        let destinationViewController: PlayerController = segue.destinationViewController as! PlayerController

        destinationViewController.currentSession = loginSession
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Which view controller is not getting the session? Why do declare both currentSession and loginSession variables?

Comment: The one with the player, (PlayController) doesn't get the session.

I had the currentSession and loginSession, bc if I remove one of them, I get or this error at the ViewController:

'Value of Type 'PlaylistlistController' has no member of 'currentSession'

Or I get at the PlaylistController:

'Use of unresolved identifier 'loginSession'

Comment: In the demo code on GitHub, the NowPlayingController only declares currentSession. I don't think you want two different session objects. Also that examples calls a login method with the currentSession object, probably to re-establish the session.

Comment: YEAH! I just changed the 'destinationViewController.currentSession = loginSession' to 'destinationViewController.currentSession = currentSession', thank you so much!! You're amazing!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, just changed

```
destinationViewController.currentSession = loginSession
```

to

```
destinationViewController.currentSession = currentSession
```

and deleted the var loginsession in the PlaylistController.